# How to get image over div ::before?

Tags: css

Image hidden by `::before`:
[image: Image hidden by ::before]

```
.footer::before {
display: block;
content: "";
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
width: 0;
height: 0;
background: none;
border-bottom: 5vw solid transparent;
border-left: 100vw solid #ffffff;
z-index: 0;}
```

To get a triangle like shape I made the border of left border white. 
But I want an image over the div like

How I want image to be:

[image: How I want image to be]

But it is hiding behind the ::before

```
 img {
z-index: 10;
margin: 5px;}
```

How to get image above the border of ::before?

Footer is

```
 .footer {
height: 200px;
width: 100%;
left: 0;
background-image: linear-gradient(-315deg, #53BF9D 48%, #195CA0);
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;}
```

HTML

```
    <div class="footer">
    <img src="logo.png" width="200">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just give your img `position : relative` because `z-index` doesn't work without `position` relative or absolute